# Easy way to implement a Root Raised Cosine (RRC) filter using Python & Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

SciPy/Numpy seems to support many filters, but not the root-raised cosine filter.  Is there a trick to easily create one rather than calculating the transfer function?  An approximation would be fine as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `commpy` package has several filters included with it.  The order of return variables was switched in an earlier version (as of this edit, current version is 0.8.0).  To install, follow instructions [here](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-commpy/) or [here](https://github.com/veeresht/CommPy).

Here's an example for 1024 symbols of QAM16:

```
import numpy as np
from commpy.modulation import QAMModem
from commpy.filters import rrcosfilter
N = 1024  # Number of symbols. Also, the filter length in samples.
os = 8    # Over-sampling factor
# Create modulation. QAM16 makes 4 bits/symbol
mod1 = QAMModem(16)
# Generate the bit stream for N symbols
sB = np.random.randint(0, 2, N*mod1.num_bits_symbol)
# Generate N complex-integer valued symbols
sQ = mod1.modulate(sB)
sQ_upsampled = np.zeros(os*(len(sQ)-1)+1,dtype = np.complex64) 
sQ_upsampled[::os] = sQ
# Create a filter with limited bandwidth. Parameters:
#      N: Filter length in samples
#    0.8: Roll off factor alpha
#      1: Symbol period in time-units
#     os: Sample rate in 1/time-units
sPSF = rrcosfilter(N, alpha=0.8, Ts=1, Fs=os)[1]
# Analog signal has N/2 leading and trailing near-zero samples
qW = np.convolve(sPSF, sQ_upsampled)
```

Here's some explanation of the parameters. `N` is the number of baud samples. You need 4 times as many bits (in the case of QAM) as samples. I made the `sPSF` array return with `N` elements so we can see the signal with leading and trailing samples. See the [Wikipedia Root-raised-cosine filter page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-raised-cosine_filter) for explanation of parameter `alpha`. `Ts` is the symbol period in seconds and `Fs` is the number of filter samples per `Ts`. I like to pretend `Ts=1` to keep things simple (unit symbol rate). Then `Fs` is the number of complex waveform samples per baud point.

If you use return element 0 from `rrcosfilter` to get the sample time indexes, you need to insert the correct symbol period and filter sample rate in `Ts` and `Fs` for the index values to be correctly scaled.

Comment: Great, thanks!  A description of the parameters is available here:

http://commpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generated/commpy.filters.rrcosfilter.html

Comment: can you please explain those lengthes and parameters? it looks like you are the only usage example for that library around..

what is ```mod1.num_bits_symbol*N*M/4```? and why rrcosfilter() gets ```N*4```?

also how does the ```Ts=1``` and ```Fs=24``` affect here?

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to have the root-raised cosine filter standardized in a common package. Here is my implementation in the meantime based on commpy. It vectorized with numpy, and normalized without consideration of the symbol rate.

```
def raised_root_cosine(upsample, num_positive_lobes, alpha):
    """
    Root raised cosine (RRC) filter (FIR) impulse response.

    upsample: number of samples per symbol

    num_positive_lobes: number of positive overlaping symbols
    length of filter is 2 * num_positive_lobes + 1 samples

    alpha: roll-off factor
    """

    N = upsample * (num_positive_lobes * 2 + 1)
    t = (np.arange(N) - N / 2) / upsample

    # result vector
    h_rrc = np.zeros(t.size, dtype=np.float)

    # index for special cases
    sample_i = np.zeros(t.size, dtype=np.bool)

    # deal with special cases
    subi = t == 0
    sample_i = np.bitwise_or(sample_i, subi)
    h_rrc[subi] = 1.0 - alpha + (4 * alpha / np.pi)

    subi = np.abs(t) == 1 / (4 * alpha)
    sample_i = np.bitwise_or(sample_i, subi)
    h_rrc[subi] = (alpha / np.sqrt(2)) \
                * (((1 + 2 / np.pi) * (np.sin(np.pi / (4 * alpha))))
                + ((1 - 2 / np.pi) * (np.cos(np.pi / (4 * alpha)))))

    # base case
    sample_i = np.bitwise_not(sample_i)
    ti = t[sample_i]
    h_rrc[sample_i] = np.sin(np.pi * ti * (1 - alpha)) \
                    + 4 * alpha * ti * np.cos(np.pi * ti * (1 + alpha))
    h_rrc[sample_i] /= (np.pi * ti * (1 - (4 * alpha * ti) ** 2))

    return h_rrc
```

Answer (score 1):

commpy doesn't seem to be released yet.  But here is my nugget of knowledge.

```
beta = 0.20 # roll off factor

Tsample = 1.0 # sampling period, should at least twice the rate of the symbol

oversampling_rate = 8 # oversampling of the bit stream, this gives samples per symbol
# must be at least 2X the bit rate

Tsymbol = oversampling_rate * Tsample # pulse duration should be at least 2 * Ts
span = 50 # number of symbols to span, must be even
n = span*oversampling_rate # length of the filter = samples per symbol * symbol span

# t_step must be from -span/2 to +span/2 symbols.
# each symbol has 'sps' number of samples per second.
t_step = Tsample * np.linspace(-n/2,n/2,n+1) # n+1 to include 0 time

BW = (1 + beta) / Tsymbol
a = np.zeros_like(t_step)

for item in list(enumerate(t_step)):
    i,t = item 
    # t is n*Ts
    if (1-(2.0*beta*t/Tsymbol)**2) == 0:
        a[i] = np.pi/4 * np.sinc(t/Tsymbol)
        print 'i = %d' % i
    elif t == 0:
        a[i] = np.cos(beta * np.pi * t / Tsymbol)/ (1-(2.0*beta*t/Tsymbol)**2)
        print 't = 0 captured'
        print 'i = %d' % i 

    else:
        numerator = np.sinc( np.pi * t/Tsymbol )*np.cos( np.pi*beta*t/Tsymbol )
        denominator = (1.0 - (2.0*beta*t/Tsymbol)**2)
        a[i] =  numerator / denominator

#a = a/sum(a) # normalize total power

plot_filter = 0
if plot_filter == 1:

    w,h = signal.freqz(a)
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.title('Digital filter (raised cosine) frequency response')
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
    plt.plot(w/np.pi, 20*np.log10(abs(h)),'b')
    #plt.plot(w/np.pi, abs(h),'b')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude (dB)', color = 'b')
    plt.xlabel(r'Normalized Frequency ($\pi$ rad/sample)')

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    angles = np.unwrap(np.angle(h))
    plt.plot(w/np.pi, angles, 'g')
    plt.ylabel('Angle (radians)', color = 'g')
    plt.grid()
    plt.axis('tight')
    plt.show()


    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.stem(a)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct response is to generate the desire impulse response. For a raised cosine filter the function is

```
h(n) = (sinc(n/T)*cos(pi * alpha* n /T)) / (1-4*(alpha*n/T)**2)
```

Select the number of points for your filter and generate the weights.

```
output = scipy.signal.convolve(signal_in, h)
```

Comment: I don't see how the rrc filter can be implemented with a sinc function, based on wikipedia definition.

Comment: @nedlrichards found this equation here https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20120008631/downloads/20120008631.pdf#page=7

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I think that this formulation is a form of Eq. 2 in the pdf, which is a raised cosine filter. This clarified for me what the original answer was doing. However, since the original question concerned the raised root cosine filter, I do not think this is the requested solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same function as in CommPy but much smaller in code:

```py
def rcosfilter(N, beta, Ts, Fs):
    t = (np.arange(N) - N / 2) / Fs
    return np.where(np.abs(2*t) == Ts / beta,
        np.pi / 4 * np.sinc(t/Ts),
        np.sinc(t/Ts) * np.cos(np.pi*beta*t/Ts) / (1 - (2*beta*t/Ts) ** 2))
```

Comment: This is Raised Cosine, not **root**-Raised Cosine!